# Excel VBA UpdatePivotCache results in Error 438 - Object Doesn't support Property or method

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have a spreadsheet that generates a summary of a Database query as Pivot Charts. This database query was written by a 3rd party and works very well, except that it deletes everything in the worksheet and rewrites all of the data in that same sheet. To work with this, I've written a macro to do some minor re-arranging of the data, and then update the cache of the Pivot Tables. I would like the Pivot Tables themselves to persist, as the filters and parameters of the Pivot Tables will not change between updates.

Here's the code that I wrote to accomplish this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim SrcData As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sh = wb.Sheets("Data")

'Find Last Row of Data
Lastrow = sh.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    
' STEP 2 - Update Pivot Tables

' Set Source Data
SrcData = sh.Name & "!" & sh.Range("$A1:$CS" & Lastrow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
Set pvtCache = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

' Change Pivot Cache to current Range and Refresh for all Pivot tables in Sheet
For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
    For Each pvt In sht.PivotTables
' ERROR 438 - Object Doesn't support Property or method
        pvt.ChangePivotCache (pvtCache)
        'sht.PivotTables(pvt).ChangePivotCache (pvtCache) ' Attempt 2
        'sht.PivotTables(pvt).ChangePivotCache (wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)) ' Attempt 2 - Longhand pvtCache
' ERROR 1004 - Method 'PivotTables' of object '_Worksheet' failed
        pvt.PivotCache.Refresh
    Next pvt
Next sht
```

The error occurs on the line:

```
 pvt.ChangePivotCache (pvtCache)
```

Every reference I've seen says that this should be a legitimate way to change the Pivot Cache, but it gives me an "Error 438 - Object Doesn't support Property or Method" every time. I've also tried to do it outside the loop with this code:

```
    ' Update WeekStops
Set sht = wb.Sheets("Stops by Week")
sht.PivotTables("WeekStops").ChangePivotCache (wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15))
sht.PivotTables("WeekStops").PivotCache.Refresh
```

The Error 438 still occurs on the ChangePivotCache command.

Could it be related to the Error 1004 that happens on the next line

```
pvt.PivotCache.Refresh
```

when I comment out the line above it?

Thanks and Best Regards,

John

Comment: Try - `pvt.ChangePivotCache  pvtCache` : should not use parentheses around your arguments if not calling a function

Comment: From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pivottable.changepivotcache.aspx): "The ChangePivotCache(Object) method can only be used with a PivotTable that uses data stored on a worksheet as its data source. A run-time error will occur if the ChangePivotCache(Object) method is used with a PivotTable that is connected to an external data source."

Comment: @ Tim - when I do this I get 'Error 5 - invalid procedure call or argument' - does that mean there's something wrong with the creation of pvtCache?

Comment: @ Comintern - The data that I'm referencing is in another worksheet in the same workbook, as far as I can tell that doesn't make it external - is there more to it than that?

Answer (score 1):

The Issue was in the creation of pvtCache external to the ChangePvtCache command, as well as using parentheses in ChangePivotCache.

The working code looks like:

```
pvt.ChangePivotCache wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)
```

Thanks everyone for your help.